# Change default Vuetify dark theme background color

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use the vuetify dark theme for my app, but I don't want the default #303030 background color applied to all lists and navigation drawers. I tried using the solution here to change the background:

> https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1222

```
.application--dark,
.list,
.navigation-drawer {
    background: #570505;
}
```

But #303030 was still applied to everything. How can I change it?

Comment: Use `!important`? Increase selector specificity?

Comment: !important doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Github issue is outdated, classes changed in recent version. Now in newer versions that should compile to something like `.application.theme--dark .v-list,
.application.theme--dark .v-navigation-drawer {
  background: #570505;
}`